# Ninject WithConstructorArgument not overriding global binding for type?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, constructor-injection

I have my general bindings, and one of which is this:

```
Bind<IHasher>().To<SHA256Hasher>();
```

This works great, as there are a few classes throughout which use this hasher. However there are one or two controllers which require another type of hasher for using the hash with 3rd parties, such as gravatar which expect md5 hashes. So then I do the below:

```
Bind<ISomeController>().To<SomeController>().Named("SomeController").WithConstructorArgument("emailHasher", new Md5Hasher());
```

Then my controller looks like:

```
    public class SomeController : Controller
    {
        private IHasher emailHasher;

        public CampaignController(IHasher emailHasher)
        {
            this.emailHasher = emailHasher;
        }
    }
```

When debugging I would expect the IHasher to be Md5Hasher, however it is an Sha256Hasher. So is this expected behaviour and any way to make it use the overridden type?

Comment: Usually controlles resolved by their types and not by some interface, also you don't need to register them `Named` so try the with the registration : `Bind<SomeController>().ToSelf().WithConstructorArgument("emailHasher", new Md5Hasher());`

Comment: There is a reason for this which is outside the bounds of this question, as I use a plugin style architecture and controllers are accessed by names, but I just wanted to put it in incase it was something which could effect the injection process around this area. So there is a reason why there is an interface with a concrete type and a naming criteria.

Comment: `WithConstructorArgument` should work as expected, so there is something else in your custom  plugin style architecture which causes your problem... maybe your controller registrations not called in the correct order and your `WithConstructorArgument` registration later gets overridden with some default...

Comment: ok, just wanted to see if there was some known issue or gotchas before I went down this rabbit hole.

Comment: Just to prove or disprove I have moved to use the default `Bind<Type>().ToSelf().Named("blah").WithConstructorArgument("blah", type);` as a test and it works, so if you put your comment as the answer will give you the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this is an MVC controller. The MVC Framework will resolve a `SomeController` not an `ISomeController`. Hence your binding does not apply but Ninject will use the implicit binding `SomeController` `ToSelf` instead.

Create a binding for `SomeController` `ToSelf` instead.

Comment: The actual use case is a bit more complicated with custom controller factories and things, so it works off interfaces and named bindings rather than the interface, as they are all IControllers to allow for runtime plugins to hook into without knowing the type. Anyway given you the answer as this would be a way to solve it in any *normal* use-case.